# Connecting XRAID to Sunfire via LSI FC card - Drives not showing up

Tags: solaris, raid

I've got a Sunfire T1000 machine ( Solaris 10 10/09 s10s_u8wos_08a SPARC ) with a LSI7404EP-LC fibre channel card in it. This is plugged into an XRAID.

The system seems to have picked up the card

```
> /usr/platform/`uname -i `/sbin/prtdiag

            IO                                                                                         
Location    Type  Slot Path                                          Name                      Model   
----------- ----- ---- --------------------------------------------- ------------------------- ---------
MB/PCIE0   PCIE      0                        /pci@780/fibre-channel             fibre-channel          
MB/PCIE0   PCIE      0                        /pci@780/fibre-channel             fibre-channel          
MB/NET0    PCIE     MB                      /pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4      network-pci14e4,1668          
MB/NET1    PCIE     MB                    /pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4,1      network-pci14e4,1668          
MB/NET2    PCIX     MB                /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/network@1      network-pci108e,1648          
MB/NET3    PCIX     MB              /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/network@1,1      network-pci108e,1648          
MB/PCIX    PCIX     MB                   /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@8/scsi@2           scsi-pci1000,50  LSI,1064
```

However it doesn't seem to be able to see the xraid attached to it, lsiutil only reports the onboard SAS controller.

```
>  /usr/local/bin/lsiutil                                                                                                                                                                         ~ 

LSI Logic MPT Configuration Utility, Version 1.62, January 14, 2009

1 MPT Port found

     Port Name         Chip Vendor/Type/Rev    MPT Rev  Firmware Rev  IOC
 1.  mpt0              LSI Logic SAS1064 A3      105      010a0000     0

Select a device:  [1-1 or 0 to quit]
```

I've tried adding the configuration to /kernal/drv/sd.conf and /kernal/drv/ssd.conf as per [this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1220670), however format still cannot see any drives on the xraid.

I'm not sure where to go next. Any suggestions? From what I've read..this should pretty much just eb plug it in and they show up in format..

Answer (score 1):

It seems system has did not bind a driver to your device, so it cannot be used. First thing, are you sure you have [FCode](http://www.lsi.com/storage_home/products_home/host_bus_adapters/fibre_channel_hbas/lsi7404eplc/#BIOS) on it, not the x86 BIOS? Second thing, the LSI driver built into Solaris is a simplified version and it does not recognize LSI FC cards (only SCSI/SAS cards), this is described here http://www.vmunix.com/mark/blog/archives/2006/09/07/aventures-in-storage-land-damned-if-you-do-damned-if-you-dont/